# Creating subversion shell script on Centos

Tags: php, shell, svn, centos6

I have subversion installed on CentOs 6.4 and want to write a script (from my understanding a shell script) to run a couple of commands. My issue here is not writing the shell script but more providing a parameter to the shell script (so a function in a way) to be able to complete the request.

In essence I want to do the following:

1. Run script with parameter from SSH ("somscript reponame")
2. Create repo: svnadmin create /var/www/svn/reponame
3. Change repo owner: chown -R apache.apache /var/www/svn/reponame -R
4. Do security changes: chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/svn/reponame/
5. And chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_r /var/www/svn/reponame
6. Create default directories: svn import -m 'Initial import' /tmp/svn-structure-template/ http://domain.com/svn/reponame/ (localhost is not accepted by stackoverflow)

Can anyone offer some guidance or perhaps provide an alternative I can use? Would a PHP script work (so to run it from a browser and use a query string of some sort and would this not cause some security issues as apache is the default owner and some of these may require root / sudo access).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the problem with a bash script with parameters ($1, $2..) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Fausto said in the comment, standard Bash parameters should work fine.  At [ProjectLocker](http://projectlocker.com), we use scripts similar to what you're describing to provision new Subversion repositories, and you should just be able to reference "$1", "$2", and so on in the script.

Incidentally, you don't have to import to the http:// location if you're running on the machine with the instance, if that makes things harder.  You can do:

```
 svn import -m 'Initial import' /tmp/svn-structure-template/ file:///var/www/svn/reponame
```

although I'd recommend testing that first to make sure that doesn't cause an undesired permissions change.  If it does, you can simply run it before the apache permission flip and the lockdown.